# Create a file from user input Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I'm making a discord bot, and I want to have a file called createcommand.js, so when you run it with node createcommand.js is starts asking for user input. So it ask "what should the name be" and then it creates a file from the input with the name, the it will ask "what should it send" and then  it will add the command in the file. I've tried with `https://pastebin.com/UARJcExh`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('file-system');
const ncp = require('ncp');
const init = async function () {
const modulee = require('../index.js')
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  })
const name =
      
      
readline.question(`Welcome, what should the name of the command be?`, (input) =>{
  js.name = input
  
 
let config = {}

  readline.question(`What should it output`, (input) => {
    js.output = input;
    
  
    readline.close();
    
  })
})
}
var js = `
        exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => {
 message.channel.send(output)
};

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: false,
  aliases: [],
  permLevel: "User"
};

exports.help = {
  name: "support",
  category: "Miscelaneous",
  description: "",
  usage: name
};
    
module.exports = config;`;
 fs.appendFile(`${js.name}`, js ,function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }})

init();
```

. But it doesn't work.

Comment: `But it doesn't work.` any errors? You also override `js` so `js.name` is `undefined`.

Comment: You declared js as a string and then you tried to use it as an object. That's not going to work. Maybe you intent to do this: `const js = { name: 'Filename', code: 'YOUR_CODE' }`. Also, if you are trying to use `fs`, the require should be `const fs = require('fs')`.